# Firebase onVerificationCompleted not calling from 10th January

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

As of January 10, 2019 Firebase Phone Auth **onVerificationCompleted** is not called automatically.

I know about the new SMS Retrieval API.
Is this anything to do with Firebase Phone Auth?

Also, I couldn't find any documentation on Firebase Auth related to this.

I am using my own Custom UI which was working fine before mentioned date

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any [currently known outages](https://status.firebase.google.com/) in SMS/phone number verification. You might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, since they typically have a better view across all apps.

Comment: I have submitted the bug. The root of the bug lies in SMS Template. I changed SMS template to English and everything starts to work normally.  I have submitted the bug report for other custom languages